# Pseudo Random number generation in C using libsodium

Tags: c, libsodium

I am trying to create a sequence of integers which is the same everytime as the generator is seeded however I am struggling to get it working. Right now the sequence is never the same.

```
#include "sodium.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    if (sodium_init() == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned int myInts[128];
    char seed[randombytes_SEEDBYTES] = "a seeeeeed";
    printf("%s", seed);

    randombytes_buf_deterministic(myInts, 128, seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        printf("\n(%u)", myInts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated: prefer the newline at the end of the *format string* `printf("(%u)\n", myInts[i]);`

Comment: @Yunnosch Hm, `seed` should be fully initialized in any case, or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Yeah sorry I didnt get what you meant @Yunnosch. I did also try this to initialize the seed:

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= randombytes_SEEDBYTES; i++)
    {
        seed[i] = 's';
    }

Comment: but this didnt work aswell

Comment: The `<=` will break the array bounds, use `<`

Comment: @Yunnosch In this case the rest of the char array has to be initialized with zero-bytes

Comment: @Yunnosch The c standard requires it at least, so most sane compilers should comply ;)

Comment: I see (from accepted answers explanation) that I was wrong with my target, but not far off with my hunch. :-)

Comment: @Yunnosch Indeed ;)

Comment: @Lamebro1 I was wrong, sorry for confusing you.

Comment: No worries thank you for contributing to the conversationn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that here

```
randombytes_buf_deterministic(myInts, 128, seed);
```

you generate 128 bytes of pseudorandom-data, but your buffer

```
unsigned int myInts[128];
```

is `sizeof(int)*128` bytes big. So you have to generate enough data with

```
randombytes_buf_deterministic(myInts, sizeof(myInts), seed);
```

to fill the whole buffer with deterministic values. Then it should give the output you expect.